# Why is the following set linearly independent over the Field $L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

The author is trying to prove that if $[L:K]$ is finite, then there must exist finitely many elements in $L$ fuch that $L = K(a_1, ..., a_s)$ and $L$ must be algebraic over $K$.

The first part I understand, but I don't get why $L$ is algebraic over $K$. The author proves it this way:

Let $x$ be any element of $L$ and let $n=[L:K]$. The set ${1, x, ..., x^n}$ has $n+1$ elements, so it must be linearly independent over $K$. (...)

---

From the assumption ${1, x, ..., x^n}$ is linearly dependent over $K$ the theorem is easily proved. Though how can one prove that such set is linearly independent over $K$ for all of the elements in $L$?

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts!

Comment: Next $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module iff $\alpha^d = \sum_{n=0}^{d-1} c_n \alpha^n$ (so that  $\alpha$ is the root of a monic polynomial : an algebraic integer)

Answer (score 3):

There's a typo in your statement:

> Let $x$ be any element of $L$ and let $n=[L:K]$. The set $1,x,\ldots,x^n$ has $n+1$ elements, so it must be linearly **independent** over $K$.

In fact, the highlighted word must be **dependent**. Please check whether the typo was in your book of whether you made it here. They are dependent simply because there are too many of them, viz. $n+1$ elements.

Now, their dependence means that there exists their linear combination
$$c_0\cdot1+c_1\cdot x+\cdots+c_n\cdot x^n=0,$$
which is precisely what we need.

Comment: The typo was made here, thank you for pointing that out. Though, how is it that the fact that they are 'too many' proves they are dependent??

Comment: @Leo Do you understand the definition of $[L : K]$?  And the dimension of a vector space?

Comment: @Leo: Because they are $n+1$ elements in an $n$-dimensional vector space.